# Codeigniter: update_batch not escaping field names

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, escaping

I am trying to use the `update_batch()` function from the Active Record helper in Codeigniter as follows:

```
var_dump($data);
$this->db->where('event_id',$data['event_id']);
$this->db->update_batch('results',$data['results'],'uid');
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

This prints out the following:

```
array(2) {
  ["event_id"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["results"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["uid"]=>
      string(36) "1beab26d-f705-11e0-a190-f46d048dfd25"
      ["res"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["uid"]=>
      string(36) "9dcc9e0a-bf24-11e0-838c-f46d048dfd25"
      ["res"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
UPDATE results SET res = CASE 
WHEN uid = '1beab26d-f705-11e0-a190-f46d048dfd25' THEN '2'
WHEN uid = '9dcc9e0a-bf24-11e0-838c-f46d048dfd25' THEN '1'
ELSE res END WHERE `event_id` = '11' AND uid IN ('1beab26d-f705-11e0-a190-f46d048dfd25','9dcc9e0a-bf24-11e0-838c-f46d048dfd25')
```

Obviously, this is a large security hole because the field and table names are not being escaped from the `update_batch` section (although they are escaped in the `where` section). Am I doing something wrong? This behaviour is not specified in the docs:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update

Comment: Actually looks like a bug/oversight, but unless you pass table names in dynamically, I can't see that not escaping them would cause trouble. Could you give an example where this could cause a security issue?

Comment: The $data is from user input and cannot trusted.

Comment: Ah, 'res' and 'uid' are passed in as data, that _would_ be a security problem... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, according to the documentation for the update_batch() function, they just claim that

> "values are automatically escaped producing safer queries"

with these words, I see implied that fields and table names are not protected.

But in the "queries" page, they kind of contradict by saying:

> In many databases it is advisable to protect table and field names -
>   for example with backticks in MySQL. Active Record queries are
>   automatically protected, however if you need to manually protect an
>   identifier you can use:
>
> $this->db->protect_identifiers('table_name');

And IIRC it's true, AR always wraps names in backticks (that's why you need to pass FALSE, usually, to the active record method if you don't want escaping to mess with your query part).

**EDIT:**

Uhm, I just went rapidly over the code, and it looks like **it *is* escaped**:

```
// Batch this baby
for ($i = 0, $total = count($this->ar_set); $i < $total; $i = $i + 100)
{
   $sql = $this->_update_batch($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), array_slice($this->ar_set, $i, 100), $this->_protect_identifiers($index), $this->ar_where);

   $this->query($sql);
}
```

So, migth really be a bug; So far, if your table names aren't dynamically generated, you can simply ignore this and be safe anyway; or you could run the `protect_identifiers()` method and do that yourself (wrong in principle, but hey...).

You can try and reproduce the bug more than once, and then file [**a bug report**](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues)

Comment: The `$data` array is sent in from an ajax query. So the input can't be trusted as safe. Plus, the usage in the example has fields escaped with backticks. Maybe this really is a bug.

Comment: Yeah, they should backticked, true. What db driver are you using, btw? I didn't see bug reports on this (just skimmed over the list, though), maybe file one at the bug tracker